# Two Dimensional Array with 2 Class. (Array.java, ArrayTestDrive.java)

Tags: java, arrays

Array.java:

```
public class Array {
    private double[][] recordGrade;

    public Array(){
        recordGrade = new double[5][2];
    }

    public double[][] getrecordGrade() {
        return recordGrade;         
    }

    public void setrecordGrade(double[][] recordGrade){
        this.recordGrade = recordGrade;
    }
```

ArrayTestDrive.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayTestDrive {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Array a = new Array();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input Grades from 0.0 to 100.00");


        System.out.print("Enter grade at row[0] col[0]: ");
        //a.getrecordGrade(a.setrecordGrade([0][0])) = a.getinput00() = s.nextDouble();
        a.setrecordGrade([0][0]) = a.getinput00() = s.nextDouble(); //PROBLEM
```

Problem is I don't know how to write this code. I need to get the [0][1] from the other class. so that I can enter and write a value for [0][0].

Comment: Would you know how to write a method for `Array` (lousy name, btw) where you supplied the indices of the element that you wanted, and it returned that element of `recordGrade`?

Comment: The goals is to

The array size should be five rows and two columns.
The array type should be double.
The application should ask for grades from 0.0 to 100.0 only. 

The entry should be in the order listed below and the required message should be:
 Enter grade at row[0] col[0]: (and so on)
 
The array must be filled with grades.
The application should display all the encoded grades, arranged in row and column format, compute the average of all encoded grades per row and per column, display the highest grade per row, column, and the entire array.

Comment: What makes you think that your response, in any way, answers my question?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the input value to the row 0 and col 0 of the array directly. a.getrecordGrade() return you the reference to the array.

```
a.getrecordGrade()[0][0] = s.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use methods with indexes as parameters:

```
public double getRecordGrade(int i, int y) {
        return recordGrade[i][y];         
    }

    public void setRecordGrade(int i, int y, double value){
        this.recordGrade[i][y] = value;
    }
```

Then call it with proper parameters:

```
double value = s.nextDouble();
a.setrecordGrade(0, 0, value);
```